# WSO2 Identity Server: Authorization failure caused by Thread Death

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 installation configured with a read-only LDAP user store following: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+a+Read-only+LDAP+User+Store

This is the (edited) **user-mgt.xml**: https://pastebin.com/qy9PGbnP

The setup works for a while, but after some time (around 6 or more hours) I get the following error whenever any user tries to login.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-12-12 08:35:21,895] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} - Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block
```

Full trace: https://pastebin.com/yhEBQE4V

Since this issue is hard to reproduce (I have to wait until it happens again after restarting). Is there anything that could help me debug this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It was a firewall between the application server and the database.

Problem solved after adding these parameters to the master-datasources.xml

```
<maxAge>1800000</maxAge>
<timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis>750000</timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis>
<minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>750000</minEvictableIdleTimeMillis>
```